# How to append to a file as sudo?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo

I want to do:

`echo "something" >> /etc/config_file`

But, since only the root user has write permission to this file, I can't do that. But the following also doesn't work.

```
sudo echo "something" >> /etc/config_file
```

Is there a way to append to a file in that situation without having to first open it with a `sudo`'d editor and then appending the new content by hand?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 9.04 and am able to use sudo for every command I've needed to so far. Spawning a sub-shell worked.

Comment: Strongly related: [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/23408) (on Unix & Linux).   Weakly related: [`ls` with directory path shows files, but `ls` with file pattern does not?](http://superuser.com/q/893761/150988)

Answer (score 468, accepted):

Use [`tee -a`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) (or `tee --append`) with `sudo`

```
tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
[...]
   -a, --append
      append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
[...]
```

So your command becomes

```
echo "something" | sudo tee -a /etc/config_file
```

The advantages of `tee` over executing Bash with administrative permissions are

- You do not execute Bash with administrative permissions
- Only the 'write to file' part runs with advanced permissions
- Quoting of a complex command is much easier

Comment: On OS X tee only seems to have an -a flag.

Comment: Debian 8 `tee` has the `-a` append flag.

Comment: Use `echo "output" | sudo tee -a file > /dev/null` if you want to skip console output.

Comment: Works well for WSL as well.

Comment: What if `"something"` is some _secret_ value, that you don't want to be outputted to the terminal and potential be saved in logs etc.?

Comment: It would be nice if sudo itself had such a feature to avoid having to use `tee` and having to redirect standard output to `/dev/null`. Something like `echo "something" | sudo --out /etc/config_file`.

Answer (score 59):

The redirection is executed in the current shell. In order to do the redirection with elevated privileges, you must run the shell itself with elevated privileges:

```
sudo bash -c "somecommand >> somefile"
```

Answer (score 26):

Have sudo spawn a sub-shell:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun' >> /etc/profile"
```

In this example, sudo runs "sh" with the rest as arguments.

(this is shown as an example in the sudo man page)

Comment: The reason is that it's your shell (running as you) that does the redirection, not sudo.  Since you don't have permission to write to the file, you get the Permission denied error.  What this answer does is to start a new shell that is running as root, and therefore is able to write to the file.

Comment: This is not the right answer.  This is a right answer.  Akira's got a better one, for the logic provided in that answer.

Answer (score 13):

I usually use [shell HERE document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) with **sudo tee -a**. Something along the lines of:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/java.sh << 'EOF'
# configures JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the best in this case is dd:

```
sudo dd of=/etc/profile <<< END
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
END
```

Comment: Be careful.  This command would overwrite /etc/profile.  You should add "conv=notrunc oflag=append" arguments to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple and puts `sudo` first, as it is common.

```
sudo sed -i '$a something' /etc/config_file
```

`$a` means to append at the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a problem with the sudo here and the redirecting. Use a texteditor of your choice instead to add the line.

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

Or, you could try su instead

```
su
echo ‘JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun’ >> /etc/profile
exit
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produced the same result.

Comment: `su -c 'echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun" >> /etc/profile'` should work.  since there's nothing the shell can mistakenly expand in the arg to echo, single-quote the overall command.

Comment: That's fantastic. Now do this as part of a script.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work you are trying to redirect (using `>>`) the output of sudo. What you really want to do is redirect the output of `echo`. I suggest you simply use your favorite editor and add that line manually to `/etc/profile`. This has the additional benefit that you can check whether `/etc/profile` already sets `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-way:

```
sudo ex +'$put =\"FOO\"' -cwq /etc/profile
```

and replace `FOO` with your variable to append.

In some systems (such as OS X), the `/etc/profile` file has 444 permissions, so if you still getting *permission denied*, check and correct the permission first:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/profile
```

then try again.