# bash: /etc/shells: Permission denied in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, permissions, shell, xonsh

I am trying to add Xonsh to my `/etc/shells`to make it my new default shell, however when i run `sudo which xonsh >> /etc/shells` I get `bash: /etc/shells: Permission denied` I tried changing the permissions using `chmod u+x /etc/shells`but it throws `changing permissions of '/etc/shells': Operation not permitted` what can i do?

Comment: Did you try `chmod` without `sudo` or did you just forget to include that in your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append to a file as sudo?](https://superuser.com/questions/136646/how-to-append-to-a-file-as-sudo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output redirection `>>` is perhaps tried to be applied
by the shell before the `sudo` is executed, but the
user shell has no permission to do that.

To avoid the error, the following two formulations
might work :

```
sudo sh -c "echo $(which xonsh) >> /etc/shells"

echo $(which xonsh) | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```